# Phone number Format in DOM using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have tentative new phone number - 559907XXXX. I need to change its format to (111)-111-1111. This phone number is inside span and ot in input field so i am unable to use mask.

```
  $('.phone-number').mask('(000)-000-0000');
```

Looking for solution using reg ex. Please help

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#phone").blur( function (e) {
  var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/);
  e.target.value = '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + '-' + x[3];
});
});
</script>
<body>
<p>Masked on the blur event (remove focus).</p>
<input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="(555) 555-5555"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please try this , whether you are expecting the same

Comment: Only this is sufficient in event handler `this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '($1) $2-$3');`

Comment: In my case last 4 digits are not digits but XXXX, format should be (559)-907-XXXX. So i am not getting proper response using both the ways suggested above.